# Does UTF8 encoding in Objective C's NSData and NSString adhere to RFC3629 or the original spec?

Tags: objective-c, utf-8

Does UTF8 encoding in Objective C's NSData and NSString adhere to RFC3629 or the original spec? Original spec's max byte size is 6 bytes instead of 4.